# A JavaScript Popup box is working perfectly in Coda 2 but not any browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game where you have to get from one point (task) on a site to another (dest) in an iframe. Your starting and end points are chosen for you. When the url of your starting point is equal to your end point I would like a popup box saying you won. I made one and it works fine in Coda 2 but not in any browser. I am very new to JS as well as Stack Overflow so any help would be appreciated!

How I am calling the code in my index.html:

```
<script src="assets/victory.js"></script>
```

The actual code:

```
        function victory(){
    if(url.value.substring(29, 41) == dest.value){
    window.alert("Congratulations, You Made It To Your Destination");
}
    else(null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `location.href` instead of `url.value`.

Or you can see other useful [location](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) properties in w3schools.